# Cannot instantiate Groovy class, throwing no signature of getBinding()

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have a Groovy script that includes a simple class. The method in the script tries to create an instance of the class, but it's throwing:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
TestClass.getBinding() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

The class looks like this:

```
class TestClass {
}
```

The method looks like this:

```
def testMethod {
    def testClass = new TestClass()
}
```

As soon as the code arrives at the new `TestClass` line, it throws the error. I've tried the class with static fields and I can read those fine, but the moment I try to instantiate it I get the error.

Comment: This is valid Groovy.  You're probably getting this error because of the execution context in which you're calling the code, and you have not provided any info about that so it's not possible to reproduce.

Comment: Show us how to reproduce what you are seeing... What  code do we need? What do we need to run?